# Applied differential equation regarding water clocks

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We have a [water clock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_clock), the shape defined by $r=f(h)$, and the time marks on this water clock are equally spaced.  We have to find f(h), and graph $h$ as a function of $r$, assuming the hole through which water flows is constant.

So I know that the equation used for rate of change of water height in a water clock is $\frac{dh}{dt}=-c\frac{area\:of\;hole}{area\:of\:cross\:section\:of\:water}\sqrt{2gh}$, where $c$, $area\:of\:hole$ and $g$ are all constant.  Since the time marks are evenly spaced, I know that $\frac{dh}{dt}$ is a constant.

What I've done thus far is solve for $r$, in terms of $h$, assuming $r$ is the radius of the water clock and setting $\frac{dh}{dt}=-a$, obtaining $r=\sqrt{\frac{2gr_h^2c}{a}}h^{\frac{1}{4}}$, where $r_h$ is the radius of the hole (constant).  However, I'm uncertain of my work thus far simply given that I found it in a Differential Equations textbook yet my answer required only knowledge of the meaning of the derivative, and no integration.

Comment: I think your answer is totally reasonable. And, what's your question?

Comment: Oops, sorry about that.  The objective is to find $f(h)$ and sketch a typical graph of $h$ as a function of $r$.

Comment: To do that you need to know $r(h)$.

Comment: So would $r(h)$ be $r=\sqrt{\frac{2gr_h^2c}{a}}h^{\frac{1}{4}}$?  How would I go about finding $f(h)$ then?

Comment: isn't $f(h)$ just $r$? I think you already have the answer here.

Comment: So then $f(h)=r(h)=r=\sqrt{\frac{2gr_h^2c}{a}}h^{\frac{1}{4}}$?

Comment: I guess that's it